# How to force on touch.location to work only in special place on screen?

Tags: swift, swift3

that is my first question here so - Hello Word.

I have a small problem with my code. I want to force on this program to make balls appear only if you will touch over and equal y: 650 point and boxes to appear only if you will touch under y: 650 point. x position makes here no role.

That is my code:

```
   override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    if let touch = touches.first {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        let objects = nodes(at: location)

        if objects.contains(editLabel) {
            editingMode = !editingMode
        } else {
            if editingMode {
                let size = CGSize(width: GKRandomDistribution(lowestValue: 16, highestValue: 128).nextInt(), height: 16)
                let box = SKSpriteNode(color: RandomColor(), size: size)
                box.zRotation = RandomCGFloat(min: 0, max: 3)
                box.position = location
                box.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: box.size)
                box.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false
                addChild(box)
            } else {
            let ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ballRed")
            ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.size.width / 2.0)
            ball.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ball.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask
            ball.physicsBody!.restitution = 0.4
            ball.position = location
            ball.name = "ball"
            addChild(ball)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Looking forward for help :)

Comment: You can use `y` value of the `location` in your if statements.

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked:

```
ball.position = location
if (location.y < 500) {
    ball.position.y = 500
}
```